# Insert element midway through wordpress loop according to post condition

Tags: php, wordpress

Sorry for a probably dim question but I can't find the correct terminology to find the solution.

I've got a wordpress loop [a php while loop] for my post_type event. Each post has a value with a date string. I am comparing this string with the current date. The date values start in the future and end a few years ago.

When the loop gets to posts with date values lower than the current date [`$date > $eventdate`] I want to insert some code [a divider `<article>`] and then continue my loop. How do I do this?

Seems very simple but please help as I'm stuck!

EDIT: I tried to nest two conditional while loops with the divider code in between but that was very bad. Then tried something similar with if's but I got that wrong too. Here's the [simplified] code to work with:

```
    <?php
    $date = date(Ymj);
      if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        $eventdate = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'event-date', true); ?>
    <article>post goes here</article>
      <?php endwhile; else: 
    ?>
```

Comment: Could you please post your code so far?

Comment: The manual could help? http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Comment: Added some code. It isn't really a wordpress question I don't think, more a php while loop question. [Though maybe WP has a simple solution here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$did_article = false;
$now = time();
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    $eventdate = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'event-date', true );
    $eventdate = strtotime( $eventdate );
    if ( !$did_article ) {
        if ( $now > $eventdate ) {
            $did_article = true;
            // Do special article stuff here
        }
    } ?>
    Do regular post suff here
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
$date = date(Ymj);
$datetime = strtotime($date);

  if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    $eventdate = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'event-date', true); ?>
    $eventdatetime = strtotime($eventdate); //$ventdatetime must be seconds
    if ($datetime > $eventdatetime) {
          <!--here goes the code for past events-->
    }
    <article>post goes here</article>
  <?php endwhile; else: 
?>
```